# 2007 Subaru Outback - Split AC/Heat passenger side not responsive

Tags: ac, subaru, heater, outback

As stated I have a 2007 Subaru Outback, with the LL Bean package; no LED screen yet on this one.

The AC/Heat has split controls, one for the passenger side and one for the driver.  I've always kept the two in sync as the previous owner told me this is more efficient on fuel (I never challenged that or researched why, but figure simpler is better).

Recently we noticed that the passenger side doesn't respond to heat inputs, and the driver side does.  My question is, where would I find the control and esp. switch box for this that might show a blown fuse, or at least allow me to troubleshoot?  Or is it behind the panel/controls themselves?  Here is a picture for reference:

[image: entire console picture]

Comment: You say the passenger side is "unresponsive". Are you saying you can change the heat setting from completely hot to completely cold and the air temp which comes out on that side does not change?

Comment: yes exactly, the output is just ambient temperature (best as I can tell)

Comment: any strange noises? if you hear whirring the mode actuator could need replacing which is a known issue on these cars ... https://youtu.be/3WOAp1KzmYU

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an automatic temperature system, more than likely the blend door actuator on the passenger side has quit functioning. You can pull it out and test it by applying 12vdc power to the connector pins to see if it will move. You'd have to look up a schematic for the exact motor your have, but that really shouldn't be too hard to prove one way or the other. It may even be marked on there, or you could also check the pinout of the wiring for which is power and ground. Anyway, this is the *most likely* from your description.

Comment: A blend door failing is a common fault on this gen outback.  If the OP wants to fix DIY style the diagrams and part #'s can be found at https://parts.subaru.com/